# экспортировать единственный d.ts файл из нескольких typescript файлов

Tags: typescript

Собрал пакет для публикации в npm.

Сам код содержится в одном файле, но при компиляции заголовков получается много d.ts файлов, лежащих в файловой структуре, повторяющей исходные директории.

В английском SO на аналогичный вопрос дан ответ 6 лет назад [SO English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722682/export-single-d-ts-from-several-typescript-files-entrypoint)

Попробовал разные инструменты, но нормально итоговый пакет используется только когда d.ts файлы выдаются оригинальным tsc.

Существует ли на сегодня инструмент (или опция) которая позволила бы сформировать единый файл d.ts для публикации пакета ?

Comment: посмотрите на утилиты dts-bundle-generator, dts-generator и подобные им